# yaml - How to cast value to long in yaml fil

Tags: yaml

How can I cast a value to long in yaml file. I have tried the way as like float like this:

```
value: !!long 3000
```

but it says that `class not found long`. I have tried `Long` as well.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  If you just want an arbitrarily large integer, use `!!int`

Comment: the problem is that variable is of type `long` so I can not assign it `int`. I can not modify it as it is third party plugin.

Comment: What plugin, and especially what language are you using.

Comment: I am using Asynchronous Mail Plugin using Grails

Answer (score 5):

`long` isn't a [supported YAML type](http://yaml.org/type/), so the short answer is, you cannot perform the cast in question.

As a work around, [string](http://yaml.org/type/str.html) or [binary](http://yaml.org/type/binary.html) representations would work.  Binary is more machine friendly, but strings are typically easier for people to check & edit by hand.

Answer (score 3):

If you are working with [SnakeYAML](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml) and do not need full compliancy with the YAML spec, you can use:

`value: !!java.lang.Long 30`